# fopen() not working

Tags: php, file, fopen

I'm want to read a simple string from a text file which is around 3-4 mb but fopen() fails ("can't open file" from die() is called). Here's the code:

```
clearstatcache();
$fh = fopen("/my/path/to/file.txt", "r") or die("can't open file");
$sql = fread($fh,filesize("/my/path/to/file.txt"));
```

Comment: is there such file? try without `die` to see the actual error

Comment: Did you check permissions? Also, PHP on command line and PHP through Apache work bit differently.

Comment: kumar got it >.< Post this as an answer and I'll mark it accepted...sorry for the inconvinience...

Comment: STOP upvoting these 2 nonsense comments. One have to check **certain error message**, not to tell fortunes. There are helluvalot of other reasons beside these 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you firstly checked to see if the file exists?

```
if (!file_exists("/my/path/to/file.txt") { 
    die('File does not exist');
}

clearstatcache();

$fh = fopen("/my/path/to/file.txt", "r") or die("can't open file");
$sql = fread($fh,filesize("/my/path/to/file.txt"));
```

Comment: I changed my file permissions to 777 and after adding the clearstatcache method my script started working.

Comment: THere is a missing close parentheses, but editing won't allow on a single character change :(
   if (!file_exists("/my/path/to/file.txt")) {

Answer (score 5):

you have to add to your code this line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and ALWAYS keep this line in ALL your codes

and also this line

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and keep this line only on development server.
while on the production it should be changed to

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

**By doing this you will not need Stackoverflow assistance in reading the now obvious error messages.**

Answer (score 1):

Change that second line to:

```
$fh = fopen("/my/path/to/file.txt", "r") or die($php_errormsg);
```

and see what it outputs as the cause.

Comment: @Col: I'm not a big fan of dying either but the brief is to find out why the call is failing, not to re-architect all the code :-)

Comment: there is no need to re-architect any code. just the way error messages delivered to developer

Comment: If you're going to go through and remove all the die statement, that _is_ rearchitecting. We have no idea how many thousands of those beasties may exist :-) The changing of the argument to this particular die is the minimal-impact change required to deliver the needed information.

Comment: Actually it's you who asking him to rewrite all die statements. While I am only asking to turn error_reporting on.

Comment: There's no point discussing it to death, @Col, I suspect we'll have to agree to disagree. I'm asking to only change the _one_ particular `die` that information is needed on. Once the information is gathered, the OP is free to do what they want (change it back, change them all, remove them all, whatever). The art of minimal impact discovery is a vital one to debugging, especially in the field, and it's for that reason I put forward this answer.

Comment: That's the point: there is no reason to change this one particular die, unless you're going to remove it. Moreover, putting a system error in it would be security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Try to output system errors in die or try use try…catch. Also turn on php errors while development. Also check if file is readable before open it.

Most common issues are: file does not exists (or just incorrect path provided?), there is not enough permissions to read this file.

Answer (score 0):

In your FTP *file permissions* tend to need to be `646` (or `-rw-r--rw-`), *not* `777` (always ignore those kind of comments). You want to give a key to someone you trust, setting permissions to `777` is like giving a copy of your key to *everyone*.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the specified file directory is inside the working directory. You can do this with '**getcwd'**

```
echo getcwd();
```

If you still get the error, you should check the file permissions.

```
ls -l /my/path/to/file.txt
```

If you get this output **"-rw-r--r--"** you will see the file is writable for admin only.

To make the file writable for everyone use `chmod` command:

```
chmod 666 file.txt
```

You can check again with **"ls -l"**, the z output should be **"-rw-rw-rw-"**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the permission for the PHP script itself with `chmod +x script.php` to allow the script to read/write a file with `fopen("sample_data.csv",'w+') or die("Can't open sample_data.csv")`.

Maybe it can help others!